# Is there a way to prove integral promotion to int?

Tags: c, integer, char, integer-promotion

In pure ansi C, is there any way to show that, given

```
char c1 = 1, c2 = 2;
```

the type of the following:

```
c1 + c2
```

is int?

Thanks.

NOTE: I know that according to standards it is, but in C++ you can use the typeid operator to show it. I'd like to be able to show `c1 + c2` is an int in C.

Comment: I think you can add chars, so it wont be an int

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. The problem is that in C, with no `typeid` and no function overloading, and automatic conversion between integer types, there's no way to tell the difference between `int` and another signed integer type of the same size and width. Not sure I can prove it though: that other integer type *would* have a difference conversion rank from `int`, so maybe there is some way of telling the difference based on that, and I can't think of it. C1x `_Generic` can do it, but I assume you mean the current standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking using sizeof(). Didn't check it myself. Just an idea.

Comment: works :) char c1 = 0, c2 = 0; printf("%d\n", sizeof(c1 + c2)); that prints 4

Comment: It's not explicitly guaranteed that `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char)`. But there's a problem if it isn't, since the implementation has to define `EOF` to something. Also, if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, which isn't at all unusual, then this doesn't prove that the type of the result is `int` rather than `long`.

Comment: `sizeof((float)(c1 + c2))` will most probably print 4 as well, so where is the proof?

Comment: i know that char <= short <= int <= long according to standards so i have added another condition, sizeof(int) != sizeof(char) about long or float, yes sizeof(long) == sizeof(int) and sizeof(float) == sizeof(int) but integral promotion says that they will be promoted to int or unsigned int (not long or float) and i was trying to prove that they are not chars anymore (some promotion took place regardless of values of chars and regardless of the fact that both of them are chars and there is no int), and this supports my arguement.

Comment: @Steve I know that this cannot be used in all cases. But it can be used a first level check. If a simple check suffices then why bother about more complicated one. (At least as long as the need is not for a formal case)

Answer (score 2):

You can't prove a thing like that. A C compiler is allowed to replace all operations to its liking provided that the observable result is the same as in the abstract machine. You don't have direct access to the result of the adition (being an rvalue) so the type of it is not observable nor is its size, width or signedness.

Comment: what should the observable result be on the abstract machine for this ... char c1=156, c2=101; c1+c2 ?

Comment: The result of c1+c2 is well defined as 257. If you try to store that in a variable that cannot hold the value, that's undefined behavior and we cannot expect anything in particular.

Comment: @Bo: the result of `156+101` is 257, but the result of `(char)156` isn't necessarily a value equal to 156, so `c1+c2` might be something different (indeed on my implementation it is, since `char` is signed). It's also not quite UB to assign 257 to a type smaller than that - either you get a result, or you get a signal (6.3.1.3/3). You don't get demons unless the implementation documents that the signal raised is one whose default handler causes demons.

Answer (score 0):

If c1 = 255 and x2 is 255 then when added they will add ti 510 which is too large for a char but OK for an int.

int x= c1+c2;

Comment: this is not what is asked for, this is about types and not about values

Comment: This proves that the type of `c1+c2` is not `char`, since if it was then the value couldn't be 510 (or whatever other value you've chosen, if `UCHAR_MAX > 255`). It doesn't prove that the type *is* `int`, though, it could be `short` or `double` ;-)

Comment: If the operation *was* performed on type char and char is signed and overflowing, this would be UB and could end up with a random value that just happens to be 510. What have we proved? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is c++, but I wanted to use cout because it determines the type unlike printf which needs a format specifier (ie will alter your result)

```
char c1=156, c2=101;
cout << c2 + c1 << endl;
```

output is **1** there it overflows, range is only 0 to 255, CONCLUSION: it is not an int but a char

Comment: The type of `c1+c2` is different in C++. They are not the same language so your test is meaningless...just about as meaningless as if you wrote the test in Python or Java...

Comment: fair point about language, but in c++ sizeof(c1+c2) also return 4 like the test in another answer. I don't agree with it thou. A char is a byte, Why can't you add 2 bytes together without involving ints? there was a time when bytes was the biggest address width available.

Comment: How did the output end up being 1, then? That's a much better question I guess. In any case, there is no modern reason why, but that's the way the language works. If you just convert the result (implicitly or explicitly via a cast) back down to `unsigned char`, the compiler is free to generate a pure 8-bit addition and never involve larger registers on the hardware, so it really doesn't matter so much, and usually the implicit promotions are more helpful than harmful.

Comment: the answer is 1 because of overflow. a byte's maximum number which it can store is 255, therefore 155+101 is 1 because of the implicit modulo 255 to every operation. This has happened to me in my workplace when debugging old code written when memory usage was critical

Comment: Does `c2+c1` get promoted by default promotions in C++ or not? Surely it does in C, in which case the result will NOT overflow. I don't generally use C++ and I'm not sure, but if `sizeof(c2+c1)` is 4, then `c2+c1` should not be able to overflow.

Comment: What has happened here is that `char c= 156` results (in this implementation) in the value -100. Add 101 to it, and you get 1. The type is `int`. Do `std::cout << typeinfo(c1+c2).name();`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be more the fact that integral promotion takes place on rvalues?

So `c1` and `c2` are lvalues. Only the result of `c1 + c2` is a rvalue.

So the addition should be performed on char thereby causing an overflow resulting in `1`.

But afterwards that rvalue of type `char` containing value `1` will be promoted up to a `int` preserving its value (in C++). So `cout` will see an `int` and output accordingly.

If `cout` was given a char it should output the character with the ASCII value `1` which is a non-printable character.

Comment: i don't think that addition is performed on char.